# Bind data form DataTable to DataGridView using Design

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datagridview

I am trying to bind data from a DataTable to a DataGridView using Visual Studio Design.

I have created a dataset for the table, set the DataTable and DataColumn in the dataset, and set that DataSet as the DataSource for the DataGridView.
[image]
[image]

I have created the columns I need and set the DataPropertyName for each column.

[image]

Finally, I used a function to generate some data to display on the DataGridView, but it didn't work.

```
    private void Generate_SomeData()
    {
        DataRow tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = true;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "123456789";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = false;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "AFAFAFAF";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = true;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "5555555555";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        ;

    }
```

And then I used a button to print the data in the DataTable and DataGridView.

```
    private void button_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------datatable1 data: ");

        foreach (DataRow i in dataTable1.Rows)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i[Col_Enable]}, {i[Col_SomeString]}");

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("----------------dataGridView1 data: ");

        foreach (DataGridViewRow i in dataGridView1.Rows)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.Cells[Col_dataGridView1_Enable.Name].Value}, {i.Cells[Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.Name].Value}");

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

    }
```

[image]

I know I can set up the DataSource in code to make it work, but this seems like a duplicate job since I already have it set up on Visual Studio Design.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
```

Is there anything else I need to set up on the Design to make it work?

Full Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Generate_SomeData()
    {
        DataRow tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = true;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "123456789";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = false;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "AFAFAFAF";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        tmpRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

        tmpRow[Col_Enable] = true;
        tmpRow[Col_SomeString] = "5555555555";

        dataTable1.Rows.Add(tmpRow);

        ;

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Generate_SomeData();

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;

    }

    private void button_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------datatable1 data: ");

        foreach (DataRow i in dataTable1.Rows)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i[Col_Enable]}, {i[Col_SomeString]}");

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("----------------dataGridView1 data: ");

        foreach (DataGridViewRow i in dataGridView1.Rows)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.Cells[Col_dataGridView1_Enable.Name].Value}, {i.Cells[Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.Name].Value}");

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

    }

}
```

============Update============

Full Form Designer Code:

```
partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 設計工具所需的變數。
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// 清除任何使用中的資源。
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">如果應該處置受控資源則為 true，否則為 false。</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form 設計工具產生的程式碼

    /// <summary>
    /// 此為設計工具支援所需的方法 - 請勿使用程式碼編輯器修改
    /// 這個方法的內容。
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataSet1 = new System.Data.DataSet();
        this.dataTable1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        this.Col_Enable = new System.Data.DataColumn();
        this.Col_SomeString = new System.Data.DataColumn();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.button_Check = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataTable1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataSet1
        // 
        this.dataSet1.DataSetName = "NewDataSet";
        this.dataSet1.Tables.AddRange(new System.Data.DataTable[] {
        this.dataTable1});
        // 
        // dataTable1
        // 
        this.dataTable1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Data.DataColumn[] {
        this.Col_Enable,
        this.Col_SomeString});
        this.dataTable1.TableName = "Table1";
        // 
        // Col_Enable
        // 
        this.Col_Enable.Caption = "Eanble";
        this.Col_Enable.ColumnName = "Enable";
        this.Col_Enable.DataType = typeof(bool);
        // 
        // Col_SomeString
        // 
        this.Col_SomeString.Caption = "SomeString";
        this.Col_SomeString.ColumnName = "SomeString";
        this.Col_SomeString.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable,
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString});
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.dataSet1;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 16);
        this.dataGridView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(381, 264);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button_Check
        // 
        this.button_Check.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 288);
        this.button_Check.Name = "button_Check";
        this.button_Check.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button_Check.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button_Check.Text = "Check";
        this.button_Check.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button_Check.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Check_Click);
        // 
        // Col_dataGridView1_Enable
        // 
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable.DataPropertyName = "Enable";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable.HeaderText = "";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable.Name = "Col_dataGridView1_Enable";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_Enable.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        // 
        // Col_dataGridView1_SomeString
        // 
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.DataPropertyName = "SomeString";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.HeaderText = "SomeStr";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.Name = "Col_dataGridView1_SomeString";
        this.Col_dataGridView1_SomeString.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(417, 361);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button_Check);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataTable1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Data.DataSet dataSet1;
    private System.Data.DataTable dataTable1;
    private System.Data.DataColumn Col_Enable;
    private System.Data.DataColumn Col_SomeString;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Check;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Col_dataGridView1_Enable;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Col_dataGridView1_SomeString;
}
```

Comment: in your code i don't see how dataset, datatable is declared and used.

Comment: @LeiYang OK~ Since the DataSet is a control item, as shown in the bottom left of img 2, I think I should upload the designer code.

Comment: np. i cannot open any image on this site. my suggest is don't rely on the ide generated data source. it's buggy(soon got out of control). and nowdays some orms such as dapper, or ef are much more easier to use.

Comment: @LeiYang Got it, thx.

Comment: these things came out in the year of 2005 or so. if you want to display a table in a readonly manner, the data source controls are good and really fast for development. but just that, no more. if you need update, or more logic,  avoid those controls. if you push a minimal reproducible project to github, i can help find the cause.